# Tips in String concatenation in Java 1.6 with multiple integers

Tags: java, integer, concatenation, tostring, java-6

I have a class which has 3 `int` variables named: day, month and year.
I also have a method called `toString()` that would take the three fields and return in the format "dd/mm/yyyy" (there is no need to put 0 if the day or month has only 1 number in it).

What is the best way to do this?

```
public String toString(){
        String dateString = this.day + "/" + this.month + "/" + this.year;
        return dateString;
    }
```

OR

```
public String toString(){
        String dateString = Integer.toString(this.day) + "/" + Integer.toString(this.month) + "/" + Integer.toString(this.year);
        return dateString;
    }
```

Comment: The first way looks a lot simpler.

Comment: And what about `String.format("%d/%d/%d", day, month, year)` ? You can even add leading zero in the format if you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an alternative, I would use [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) to create that `String`

```
return String.format("%d/%d/%d", day, month, year)
```

You want to format your date with leading zero ? Easy with the formatter :

```
return String.format("%02d/%02d/%02d", day, month, year)

- 0 - use leading zero instead of spaces.
- 2d - Minimum two character to print (so "2" will use " 2")
```

You can find the complete documentation about the flags allowed in [Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

A simple example :

```
String.format("%002d", 5);
```

> 005

And an example with the date,

```
String.format("%02d/%02d/%02d", 9, 5, 18);
```

> 09/05/18

Answer (score 3):

You may also write that in a single statement. There's no need to typecast `Integer` to `String` explicitly unless you're not sure that day, month and year are integers i.e. `int`, or you want to do an explicit exception handling.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return (this.day + "/" + this.month + "/" + this.year);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First one with out any doubt, in the second one you are converting Integer to  String explicitly and then again concatenating in String while returning which does not make much sense.

Comment: you meant converting integers into string and then concatenate?

Comment: Yes. Concatenating converts them to string only.

Comment: It's not converting a String to Integer first. `Integer.toString()` converts an `int` to a `String`. However it's still unnecessary.